# Decreasing labor force and GDP

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, endogenous-growth

I'm a bachelor student writing a paper on the effects of China's one child policy on future GDP. My professor told me to use growth models. However, I'm unsure which growth model I need to use for this kind of research. I'm only familiar with the Solow model and two-sector models that expands on the Solow model by introducing an R&D sector (I've seen these in their most basic form in one of my classes).

Since a major effect of the policy is a decreasing workforce, I think that technological progress (knowledge accumulation) and population growth are important, but a lot of models seem to hold population growth constant?

Answer (score 1):

An obvious way to approach this would be to compare projections based on a China without the one child policy (pre 1979 pop growth rates) and on a China with the one child policy (post 1979 pop growth rates). Pop growth rates are constant but different in the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

When people talk about growth models, they usually mean some adaptation of the Solow model.

It is a pretty ambitious task to take on this project as an undergraduate if you plan to estimate a growth model (it is ambitious for some PhDs). I would recommend looking at the one child policy using a non-econometric approach, and perhaps make reference to literature that ran a growth model that included some mention of the years or policy in question.